# grunt-connect: serve files with base url added

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, grunt-contrib-connect

I am developing jekyll-based site using grunt as my task manager.  I am using grunt-contrib-connect to serve my files locally for development because of its livereload functionality.  Those files are accessible in the browser at:

`http://localhost:8081/index.html`

On my server, my files are located within a sub-directory, so have a base url prepended to all urls:

`http://path.to.server/mysite/index.html`

I cannot figure out a way to simulate the base url on my local dev setup with grunt-connect.  Without that, I don't know how to reference my css or js files without the urls being invalid on either the server or my dev box.

I know that jekyll's serve function can add a base url, but it does not give me the livereload functionality.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Grunt Jekyll](https://github.com/dannygarcia/grunt-jekyll) to run the Jekyll build commands it has a `raw` option that lets you append things to your `_config.yml`. That way you can effectively remove `{{ site.baseurl }}` for local development

```
jekyll: {
    development: {
        options: {
            config: '_config.yml',
            raw: 'baseurl: '
        }
    },
    production: {
        options: {
            config: '_config.yml'
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20864020/79790

Basically, you can set `open` in your livereload options to be the base URL for the server you want.